# Raspberry pi. Custom partition layout

Tags: partitioning, raspberrypi

When I usually install ubuntu from scratch, I configure my own custom partition layout during installation setup (e.g /var/log, /home, and etc. on separate partitions), which is much easier than changing the partitions after installation.

This is my first time installing ubuntu on raspberry pi (ver 4). and I would like to follow my usual partition layout. However from all the guides I found, I can only dump the image on to an SD, and have no way of setting the partitions before hand. (I also usually choose to use LVM, I don't know if it's used by default- but that will be much harder to change)

What are my options here?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in changing the partition layout of the SD card before you plug it into the RPI.   However because the root filesystem is ext4 then its easiest to use a Unix/Linux computer to adjust the partitioning.

parted or gparted on another Raspberry Pi, Mac or Linux node are easily capable of this.